# what is faster - $().closest() or native while loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have my own implementation of dropdown list. I am storing all list identifiers in the global array and on `window` click event I am iterating through this array and deciding which list I have to hide.

I need to check if element has ancestor with `.active` class.

jQuery version:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < window.dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var e = window.dropdowns[i];
        if ($(event.target).closest('.active').length == 0) {
            e.hideList();
        }
    }
```

Pure javascript version:

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var e = window.dropdowns[i];
    var parent = event.target.parentElement;
    while (parent.tagName != 'BODY') {
        if (parent.className.indexOf('active') > 0) {
            e.hideList();
            break;
        }

        parent = parent.parentElement;
    }
}
```

So, what version of this will be faster? And how performance depends on number of elements on the page?

Comment: You should probably use jQuery method closest instead of parents since it will stop iterating if element is found, parents won't. Read more here https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: thanks, @Esko. But question still remains. Would `closest` be faster than `while` loop? I will update my question.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Simple performance question that can easily be tested

Comment: @JuanMendes I am especially interested in script behaviour with different element number on page. I updated my question.

Comment: jQuery is going to do more work than you need, for example, you are only testing tagName and className. Having said that, your code could give you false positives because `className.indexOf('active')` will return > -1 if the element has a class of notactive. Use classList instead. Finally, if you are already using jQuery, you should use it since we just showed you that code we write ourselves can be buggy, and performance is not likely to matter in this case

Comment: are you dealing with tens of thousands (or more) elements? If not any sort of pre-emptive optimization seems totally unessary. And if you are dealing with that many elements, that would be a great thing to include in your question

Comment: @chiliNUT The accepted answer already mentions that performance should not be a concern in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to know what's fastest, [write a simple test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38122605/227299) to find out. If you want to know why...

jQuery is going to do more work than you need, for example, you are only testing tagName and className.

Having said that, your code could give you false positives because `className.indexOf('active')` will return > -1 if the element has a class of notactive. Use classList instead.

Finally, if you are already using jQuery,  you should use it since we just showed you that code we write ourselves can be buggy, and performance is not likely to matter in this case.

Remember, premature optimization is the root of a lot of spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

If you were interested in knowing hard numbers, you could turn your loops into functions and use [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) and [`console.timeEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd) on them. Something like this:

```
//First while loop
console.time(firstWhileLoopInFunction)
console.timeEnd(firstWhileLoopInFunction)

//Second while loop
console.time(secondWhileLoopInFunction)
console.timeEnd(secondWhileLoopInFunction)
```